# Disk Activity 100% on Amazon EC2 t2.medium 4GB Ram

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Hi I want your suggestion, I have hosted node project on Amazon **ec2 t2.Medium 4GB Ram server**, and on that server I am using MySQL database. In 4 days, nearly 6000 users got registered, because of that my server disk i/o gets 100% in 1-2 hours and server stop responding. There are 4 tables which are having more than 40,00,000 records which causing 100% Disk I/O usage. Should I go for RDS or should I upgrade my server?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your machine is running low on RAM and the operating system is having to swap memory to disk. You can test this by stopping your instance, increasing the instance type and starting the instance.

By the way, the **T2-family** is not recommended for production use because it has CPU limitations. It is fine if your workload is has occasional peaks of CPU usage, but mostly uses low CPU. See: [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html)

If you wish to run a high-quality service for your users, I would certainly **recommend using Amazon RDS to separate your database from your application server.** This has the benefit that the application server can be updated/replaced without impacting the database and you could scale-out to have multiple application servers using the same database. However, it is a trade-off between application availability and cost.